# External requests to nodeport ingress nginx ends with 404

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

Im trying to run K8S cluster on bare metal servers and I have a problem accessing the apps (PODs) from the outside of cluster.

Just to sumarize my setup

- nodeported ingress nginx controller with ports for HTTP (30255) and HTTPS (32673) runnin on one node. Netstat shows the ports are open
- simple Hello World pod which runs on port 8080 (tested via nodeport that it actually works)

When I try to open the site through the nodeported ingress nginx I receive error 404.

`curl --verbose --header 'Host: hello-world.info' http://localhost:30255/`

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:30255...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 30255 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: hello-world.info
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2023 00:58:36 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 146
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I have no idea what Im doing wrong, because it should be just straight forward. Please see the configurations bellow

Configuration of the ingress for the helloworld app ("WEB" service)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target":"/$1"},"name":"example-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"hello-world.info","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"service":{"name":"web","port":{"number":8080}}},"path":"/","pathType":"Prefix"}]}}]}}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-20T00:57:59Z"
  generation: 1
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
          f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: {}
      f:spec:
        f:rules: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-02-20T00:57:59Z"
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "11184494"
  uid: 24e8a8c6-0b44-49e6-bef8-23f51ab549a6
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-world.info
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: web
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

YAML for the "WEB" service of the hello world app

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-19T23:25:50Z"
  labels:
    app: web
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
      f:spec:
        f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:ports: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
    manager: kubectl-expose
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-02-19T23:25:50Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: {}
        f:ports:
          k:{"port":8080,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: agent
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-02-20T00:21:28Z"
  name: web
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "11174849"
  uid: 68a3fb17-61c0-46c1-9c5f-fb120f66fcc0
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.105.221.158
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.105.221.158
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: web
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

YAML for the nginx ingress controller service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/version":"1.5.1"},"name":"ingress-nginx-controller","namespace":"ingress-nginx"},"spec":{"ipFamilies":["IPv4"],"ipFamilyPolicy":"SingleStack","ports":[{"appProtocol":"http","name":"http","port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":"http"},{"appProtocol":"https","name":"https","port":443,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":"https"}],"selector":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx"},"type":"NodePort"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-01-24T15:55:44Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/part-of: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/version: {}
      f:spec:
        f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:ipFamilies: {}
        f:ipFamilyPolicy: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:appProtocol: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
          k:{"port":443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:appProtocol: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-01-24T15:55:44Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:ports:
          k:{"port":443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            f:targetPort: {}
    manager: agent
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-02-20T00:12:12Z"
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  resourceVersion: "11172404"
  uid: cd4b69c6-7e8e-4b12-a5e9-16093737979c
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.102.120.71
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.102.120.71
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    nodePort: 30255
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    nodePort: 32673
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

It feels like the requests are not being recognized at the nodeport nginx and from the ingress nginx controller pod logs I see only this message from each request I send. IP address 10.244.3.1 is the internal cluster address of the node where the ingress nginx controller is running and from where I am doing the CURL requests.
`2023/02/20 01:06:25 [info] 630#630: *282876682 client 10.244.3.1 closed keepalive connection`

This is my first K8s cluster, so it would be something stupid in the config, but Im sitting on this for two weeks straight and I am out of ideas and google search possibilities. Thank you

Comment: Is the curl request being made from master node / outside k8s network.  are you able to reach master node ip using either ping or any other tool.

Comment: Hello @NatarajMedayhal . Curl was executed on the node, where the ingress nginx is running with exposed ports via nodeport. When I tried that from other servers the output is the same. Firewall is wide open in between these servers in cluster and I do not see any conflict in Rancher.